# jSSC não acha as portas USB do meu PC

Tags: java, jssc

Estou fazendo um projeto em Java utilizando a biblioteca jSSC, porém quando utilizo o método de listar as portas não aparece nada. Testei em outro computador e funcionou perfeitamente, porém no meu computador pessoal não funciona.

Já vi videos de como ativar a porta COM, porém nenhum funcionou quando utilizo o método.

```
String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();                
for(int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++){
    System.out.println(portNames[i]);
}
```

Quando executo o código abaixo ele não passa do `Serial.openPort()`.

Obs: Utilizei `"COM1"` porque através de pesquisas descobri que é a porta padrão do W10.

```
Serial = new SerialPort("COM1");
try {
    Serial.openPort();
}
catch (SerialPortException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Erro:

> ```
> jssc.SerialPortException: Port name - COM1; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Port not found.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Só para esclarecer que estamos falando da mesma coisa, a biblioteca JSSC é usada para comunicação **SERIAL**, ela não vai comunicar com seus dispositivos USB a menos que este dispositivo simule uma porta serial naquela USB (como o arduino por exemplo).

Então primeiro verifique se no seu computador tem alguma porta serial ativa.
Abra o executar e digite

> compmgmt.msc

Deve abrir a janela do Gerenciamento do computador, depois no menu lateral esquerdo vá em "Gerenciador de Dispositivo".
No lado direito vai aparecer todos os dispositivos do seu computador, quase no final da lista tem "Portas (COM e LPT)", clique para expandir o item e veja se tem alguma COM no seu computador, veja imagem abaixo.

[image: postas COM]

Se o seu computador não exibir nenhuma por COM então seu projeto esta certo, ele gera erro porque realmente não existe nada para ele se comunicar.

Comment: Qual biblioteca é indicada para comunicar com portas USB?

Comment: @CypherPotato até onde eu sei o java não tem uma biblioteca de API oficial para USB, mas existem algumas alternativas independentes como o [usb4java](http://usb4java.org/)

Comment: Sim, ele está conectado a porta COM1 no Gerenciado de Dispositivos

Comment: @Luan poderia dar mais detalhes do projeto? Qual o dispositivo você esta tentando comunicar? Qual a saída quando você manda listar as portas com o comando `SerialPortList.getPortNames();`? Qual a versão da lib JSSC você esta utilizando?